# Ionic 3 - Side menu , change side dynamically

Tags: angular, ionic3, side-menu

I want to change the direction of the side menu automatically when i change the language (rtl and ltr)
i tried this code in the page app.html

```
<ion-menu [side]="isRtl?'right':'left'" [content]="content">
```

How can i change the value of 'isRtl' from another page or example "home.ts" ?

'isRtl' is declared in 'app.component.ts'
any help guys ?

Comment: isRtl is a function or variable?

Comment: @suraj it's a var declared in 'app.component.ts', but how can i change the value of isRtl from another page for example "home.ts"

Comment: @Fray which solution is working for you. i didnt get any solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event emitor for cross component to transfer data between components

```
//Home component.ts
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';  
   constructor(public events: Events) {
      directioChange(user) {
            this.events.publish('directiochanged', 'true');
      }
   }


//App.component.ts
constructor(public events: Events) {
     events.subscribe('directiochanged', (direction) => { 
           this.isRtl = direction;console.log(direction);
     });
}
```

> not only from home component, you can set from anywhere in you project

Comment: event emitter working but dynamic side of ion-menu not working.

Comment: @Raza - i set [side] dynamically base on your code. first i set ltr. when i set rtl then can't change to ltr.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari - since [side]='value' is dynamic property , the change in the value should be by default reflect on change of value immediately. If not print the {{isRtl" in html and check weather expected value change happening or not.

Comment: in case still no luck then try to refresh the , <ion-menu *ngIf="refresh"> using ngIf, it may help ex : refresh = false; setTimeout(()=>{refresh = true;},0);  inside the event subscribe

Comment: Great, you got it.

Comment: what great ? I got errro is great

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari - Great for the right path, resolve null pointer first

Comment: how to resolve ? do you have idea? I am to resolve after very long time.